# Best way to prevent default server? (for HTTPS)

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

In Nginx (https server), how can I reject all requests for my server's IP address that don't contain the real domain name? (I would like to stop script kiddies who scan every single IP address that Digital Ocean owns!)

I'm looking for the proper HTTPS way of answering [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/420351/best-way-to-prevent-default-server) question which only works on pure HTTP.

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not re-post questions that have already been marked as duplicate questions. The answer to your question is in the other question, there isn't anything to add.